Ubuntu 24.04 and Nouveau driver: No login screen after Logout
I have an ubuntu 24.04 LTS new installation.
Hardware: CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 7600 6-Core, Graphics card: GeForce RTX 3050.
Desktop: MATE, Ubuntu (for test purpose).
When I am using the Nouveau driver (xorg), the login screen does not come up
after logout. Thus I have to turn off the computer and then boot again.
Any ideas, how to re-establish the login screen?
Incidentally: When I switch to the nvidia driver 550, it works.
